# Prevent Only Devise confirmation email while creating user through nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I am optionally creating User with Nested attributes.
 I just want to skip confirmation email . But

```
class ShipperOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipper_orders
end
```

controller

```
class ShipperOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @shipper_order = ShipperOrder.new(order_params)
    if @shipper_order.save
        flash[:notice] = "Shipper order created"
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = @shipper_order.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
        render :error
    end
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:shipper_order).permit({user_attributes: [:first_name, :email,
     :last_name,:mobile_phone, :password, :terms_of_service, :password_reset_required 
     ]}, :description)
  end
end
```

Now i am creating an order and if user want to assign this order to a User that do not exist in database. Then i am creating that user with help of nested_attributes.  Everything works fine . i just want to disable the confirmation email for such type of user.

Comment: post your controller action where you are saving user in the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add attr_accessor like

```
class User < SomeClass

    attr_accessor :skip_user_confirmation

    before_save :skip_confirm


private

  def skip_confirm
    self.skip_confirmation! if self.skip_user_confirmation 
  end

end
```

IN general it should work, but you might want to change it a little
    end

And then in controller add to `user_attributes` key `:skip_user_confirmation`, which will be `true or false`